# While building SBT compile, I need to run some class that would create the schema JSON from Case classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have created a scala project that I am bundling into Jar file and deploying the file in Databricks on Azure. I am using the assembly plugin that creates the single Jar file. As part of my build I need to create a schema JSON file from Scala Case classes, and in the runtime I would referring the json file to creating the schema.
So is there a way to run scala script after compile and before assembly.
If yes, then I would run the script that would create the schema file in json format and bundle that in the assembly and during runtime the file would be available to read data file using the schema

Answer (score 0):

SBT has quite a lot of functionality build it for this kind of thing, although I can seem a bit finicky at times. The built-in task `compile:resourceGenerators` can be used to generate additional managed resources which `assembly` will then bundle into your jar.

This example is taken from the [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html#Generate+resources):

```scala
Compile / resourceGenerators += Def.task {
  val file = (Compile / resourceManaged).value / "demo" / "myapp.properties"
  val contents = "name=%s\nversion=%s".format(name.value,version.value)
  IO.write(file, contents)
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

It adds a task to the list of tasks under `compile:resourceGenerators` which will create a file your configured `Compile / resourceManaged` setting under the path `demo`, with the filename `myapp.properties`.

If you need access to the generated bytecode you might need to play around with when the resources is generated (create a custom task which depends on `compile`).

Comment: Hello Jarrod Baker, I did not get time to test above answer, In a day or two I would be checking it